# How to change android icon in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-application

After running a flutter app, it gets correctly deployed to an Android Virtual Device.

While in the virtual device, I can notice that the icon chosen for the app shows up correctly among other existing apps.

But, when I tap to see running processes, an Android icon appears at the top of the flutter app window.

Icons were manually added as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#adding-a-launcher-icon).

How can I change this default icon to use mine?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check again your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.snapio">

<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="flutter"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

You have to change your icon name inside this file.

Comment: I already have `<application ... android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">` set, and the mimap folders have the new icon, so no idea why the emulator shows the default android icon. What do you think it could be the reason? is it missing a specific resolution? My current resolutions are hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.

Comment: Can you try uninstall the app from your phone? Then run it again.

Comment: Yes uninstalled and installed again, the same android default icon shows up. This default icon shows up only in the emulator that has an android 10.0 version. In my physical device with *android 9.0 the new icon shows up correctly*. Since in 9.0 the icon shows up correctly, so maybe it is an issue related to the android 10.0 version.

Comment: I have the same problem, shows up correctly in app drawer but not when switching apps.. Uninstall did not help. Also on android 10

Answer (score 3):

one of my favorite library that you can use
it will generate iOS and android icon for you 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Answer (score 1):

For Android 10 you have to provide an adaptive icon for it to show up in the task switcher. More info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Answer (score 1):

Change application icon in flutter from ***pubspec.yaml*** by setting the **flutter_icons** tag like this:

```
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "images/icon/icon.png" # your full path in assets directory
```

Add ***flutter_launcher_icons*** as dev dependency in ***pubspec.yaml***

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"
```

Finally update dependencies and generate the icons

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```