# How can I update the app icon badge in flutter android 10?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using the package flutter_app_badger 1.1.2 for updating icon badge programmatically. It is working fine with iOS and some android devices. It is not working with android 10. How can I use this functionality in android 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change android icon in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442634/how-to-change-android-icon-in-flutter)